# Where to find code performing filter in gimp codebase?

Tags: gimp, codebase

I was trying to find code performing https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/de/gimp-filter-snn-mean.html
in gimp codebase, but i am able to find only something looking like UI code (not actual math).

I want to peek at this code , my goal is to recreate this filter in python to implement image-processing-pieline designed by my colegue-artist in GIMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operations like filters are defined in separate repository:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gegl

this particular filter is defined here:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gegl/-/blob/master/operations/common/snn-mean.c